# Getting Error "No Element 'X' found in stack panel" when using EventTrigger from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I testing [an example I copied from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747245(v=vs.100).aspx) and just changed it a bit to meet what I need, 
But I getting an Error which looks very basic - yet I can't seem to solve it. 
Resharper saying: "No Element PlayButton Found In StackPanel",
And same error for all other routed events. 
It said the same thing for the original code even when I only changed from page to window the root element.

**The code complies and run - but the handler for `MediaOpened` will not reach.**
 so I think resharper does in fact spots the problem.

To reproduce simply create a new WPF application and copy this code, make sure the media element url path is for a movie in your machine.

So what am I doing wrong here?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Background="Black">
        <MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" Width="260" Height="150" Stretch="Fill" />
        <!-- Button controls for play, pause, resume, and stop. -->
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="260" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="PlayButton" Margin="2" Width="50" Content="Play" />
            <Button x:Name="PauseButton" Margin="2" Width="50" Content="Pause" />
            <Button x:Name="ResumeButton" Margin="2" Width="50" Content="Resume" />
            <Button x:Name="StopButton" Margin="2" Width="50" Content="Stop" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Ths slider shows the progress of the media. -->
        <Slider Name="timelineSlider" Margin="5" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseDown" SourceName="PlayButton">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name= "myBegin">

                        <Storyboard SlipBehavior="Slip">
                            <!-- The MediaTimeline controls the timing of the video and acts like other Timeline objects.  
                                 For example, although the video clip (numbers.wmv) lasts longer, playback ends after six  
                                 seconds because that is the duration of the MediaTimeline (Duration="0:0:6"). -->
                            <!--<MediaTimeline Source="C:\AgasCinemaTest\DataStore\0\10"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  
                                           BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:6" CurrentTimeInvalidated="MediaTimeChanged" />-->
                            <MediaTimeline Source="D:\DreamScene\Videos\Changer.mpg"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  
                                           BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:16" CurrentTimeInvalidated="MediaTimeChanged" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

            <!-- These triggers impliment the functionality of the Pause, Resume and Stop buttons.-->
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseDown" SourceName="PauseButton">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="myBegin" />
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseDown" SourceName="ResumeButton">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="myBegin" />
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseDown" SourceName="StopButton">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="myBegin" />
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // When the media opens, initialize the "Seek To" slider maximum value
        // to the total number of miliseconds in the length of the media clip.
        private void Element_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timelineSlider.Maximum = myMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
        }

        private void MediaTimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timelineSlider.Value = myMediaElement.Position.TotalMilliseconds;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your code looks just fine. I've tried a similar XAML code having the same structure and it just compiled and run OK. So do you mean you cannot compile and run your code? I'm not sure how Resharper works but looks like it's wrong, the code is fine (BTW - I don't use Resharper - frankly speaking it may be great in many aspects but it makes the editor ***totally uglier*** than what VS supports by default, I consider it as a mess).

Comment: @Hopeless hmm.. that's surprising news - when you say "works" - you mean you were able to see a movie with it? - you mentioned similar code - but what about this specific code?

Comment: your problem is the error `No Element PlayButton Found In StackPanel`, so I found it strange and tried a simple code without any media. The media element is not involved here.

Comment: Why dou you use <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseDown" SourceName="PauseButton"> if element PauseButton is button and not Image?

Comment: @user2250152 good query - but pointless to the solution, it didn't work when it was image - provided same error..

Comment: @Hopeless the code complies and run - but if you put breakpoint at `Element_MediaOpened` in the code behind - it will not reach it - suggesting the event trigger is not being reached.

Comment: If you re-read your question, you can see that you mentioned about errors, now you say it compiles and runs but the actual problem is no event triggered. I spotted that you declared your handlers as ***private***, it should be ***public***.

Comment: @Hopeless changed them to `public`.. nothing changed - same problem. btw, handlers can be private.. but I did made that change just to be sure that is not the problem - thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: ah yes, my bad. it's in the same scope. It should be public when the handlers are declared in separate view-model.

Comment: Well the wrong thing here is you used `MouseDown` event which will never be fired on a `Button`. It should be `PreviewMouseDown`. In fact the `MouseDown` is intercepted/handled while bubbling up. I would use `Click` event instead (actually just tested your code with `PreviewMouseDown` or `Click`, both worked perfectly). Note when using `Click`, it should be `Button.Click` because `Image` does not own that Event.

Comment: @Hopeless thank you :) it now works - if you can post your last comment as answer I'll will be happy to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: If I wanted to add it as an answer, I would have not posted it as a comment. So never mind. I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `Name` but `x:Name`.

`x:Name` is a xaml concept, used mainly to reference elements. When you give an element the `x:Name` xaml attribute, "the specified `x:Name` becomes the name of a field that is created in the underlying code when xaml is processed, and that field holds a reference to the object." (MSDN) So, it's a designer-generated field, which has internal access by default.

`Name` is the existing string property of a `FrameworkElement`, listed as any other wpf element property in the form of a xaml attribute.

Also change `Button.MouseDown` to `Button.PreviewMouseDown` and it will work.

Comment: I didn't -1 your answer if you were wondering.. but I cannot mark it as a helpful either as my problem remains.